# Auto-immune problems if immature B-cells released if bone marrow bone is fractured?

Tags: immunology, immune-system, autoimmune

A fracture of a bone containing bone marrow with B-cells not yet taught to not recognize self-antigen, if the bone is fractured, can those cells get released and cause problems?

Comment: Most likely not, because immature cells require other signals from the marrow to survive, so "spilled" cells likely wouldn't last long.

Comment: Thanks good answer, sounds evolutionarilly probable.